# Wordpress - Category list order in post edit page

Tags: wordpress

I want to stop WordPress re-ordering the category list in the admin > post edit page.  The default behaviour is to take the categories assigned to the post out of their natural parent/child flow and put them at the top of the list.  I want to stop this happening as it is confusing when the category structure is big.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>What version of Wordpress are you using? Wordpress 3.04 provides the Parent/Child tree on the Post Edit page. Are you sure you also aren't viewing the "Most Used" tab?</strike>

Nevermind, I see exactly the problem you are talking about, which show up after the post is saved:

[image: Cateogory Tree]  [image]

*Alright*, try pasting this into the `functions.php` in your theme:

```
// remove the old box
function remove_default_categories_box() {
    remove_meta_box('categorydiv', 'post', 'side');
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'remove_default_categories_box' );

// add the new box
function add_custom_categories_box() {
    add_meta_box('customcategorydiv', 'Categories', 'custom_post_categories_meta_box', 'post', 'side', 'low', array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' ));
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_categories_box');

/**
 * Display CUSTOM post categories form fields.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 *
 * @param object $post
 */
function custom_post_categories_meta_box( $post, $box ) {
    $defaults = array('taxonomy' => 'category');
    if ( !isset($box['args']) || !is_array($box['args']) )
        $args = array();
    else
        $args = $box['args'];
    extract( wp_parse_args($args, $defaults), EXTR_SKIP );
    $tax = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);

    ?>
    <div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="categorydiv">
        <ul id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-tabs" class="category-tabs">
            <li class="tabs"><a href="#<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-all" tabindex="3"><?php echo $tax->labels->all_items; ?></a></li>
            <li class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-pop" tabindex="3"><?php _e( 'Most Used' ); ?></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-pop" class="tabs-panel" style="display: none;">
            <ul id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>checklist-pop" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear" >
                <?php $popular_ids = wp_popular_terms_checklist($taxonomy); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-all" class="tabs-panel">
            <?php
            $name = ( $taxonomy == 'category' ) ? 'post_category' : 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='{$name}[]' value='0' />"; // Allows for an empty term set to be sent. 0 is an invalid Term ID and will be ignored by empty() checks.
            ?>
            <ul id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>checklist" class="list:<?php echo $taxonomy?> categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php 
                /**
                 * This is the one line we had to change in the original function
                 * Notice that "checked_ontop" is now set to FALSE
                 */
                wp_terms_checklist($post->ID, array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'popular_cats' => $popular_ids, 'checked_ontop' => FALSE ) ) ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php if ( !current_user_can($tax->cap->assign_terms) ) : ?>
    <p><em><?php _e('You cannot modify this taxonomy.'); ?></em></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( current_user_can($tax->cap->edit_terms) ) : ?>
            <div id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-adder" class="wp-hidden-children">
                <h4>
                    <a id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-add-toggle" href="#<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-add" class="hide-if-no-js" tabindex="3">
                        <?php
                            /* translators: %s: add new taxonomy label */
                            printf( __( '+ %s' ), $tax->labels->add_new_item );
                        ?>
                    </a>
                </h4>
                <p id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-add" class="category-add wp-hidden-child">
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="new<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>"><?php echo $tax->labels->add_new_item; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="new<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" id="new<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="form-required form-input-tip" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $tax->labels->new_item_name ); ?>" tabindex="3" aria-required="true"/>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="new<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>_parent">
                        <?php echo $tax->labels->parent_item_colon; ?>
                    </label>
                    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => 'new'.$taxonomy.'_parent', 'orderby' => 'name', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'show_option_none' => '&mdash; ' . $tax->labels->parent_item . ' &mdash;', 'tab_index' => 3 ) ); ?>
                    <input type="button" id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-add-submit" class="add:<?php echo $taxonomy ?>checklist:<?php echo $taxonomy ?>-add button category-add-sumbit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $tax->labels->add_new_item ); ?>" tabindex="3" />
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-'.$taxonomy, '_ajax_nonce-add-'.$taxonomy, false ); ?>
                    <span id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-ajax-response"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

The only real change was adding `'checked_ontop' => FALSE` to the args in `wp_terms_checklist()` function in the middle of that mess. Everything else is the original `post_categories_meta_box()` function.

(You could just modify the original `post_categories_meta_box()` in `/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`, but it is not recommended to mess with core and adding/removing actions as above is the proper way to do it.

[image]

Comment: I just tested this out & it works well - nice & easy solution to implement.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to be the only person annoyed by this "feature": from [Wordpress Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10982)

Comment: The above solution would mean having to recode every single custom taxonomy box setup in the edit post page.... blar

Answer (score 25):

While the above are great alternative solutions, especially if you want more control over the taxonomy checklist metabox, I think the simplest solution would be the following:

```
function taxonomy_checklist_checked_ontop_filter ($args)
{

    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    return $args;

}

add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args','taxonomy_checklist_checked_ontop_filter');
```

And that should take care of that!

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin that does just this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-checklist-tree/