# How to stop re-ordering the category list in admin "WordPress5.0"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'd like to stop re-ordering the category list in admin WordPress5.
In WordPress default, checked category comes to the top after pressing update button.
I want to avoid it and keep the order.

```
//before  I want to keep this order 
category1
category2
category3 // <-you check this

//after WordPress Default
category3
category1
category2
```

To avoid this, I used to use the function below, I mean before "WordPress5.0" but it seems not to be working in WordPress5

```php
function my_terms_checklist_arg( $args, $post_id = null ) {
    $args['checked_ontop'] = false;
    return $args;
}
add_action( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', 'my_terms_checklist_arg' );
```

Hope someone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress - Category list order in post edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830913/wordpress-category-list-order-in-post-edit-page)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I could not solve problem with that post, I'm asking about WordPress5.

Comment: @abms Change `add_action` to `add_filter` and this worked for me. There was a similar answer in Matts link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use post type order plugin in that you can order your page,post,category or any post type by just drag and drop https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed it but it seems like I can't realize it with free version...

Comment: In post type order plugin setting you can tick post type oprion  of any post type

Comment: What I need to handle is "categories", not "posts".

Comment: Use this plugin Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order. Here is link of it https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/. And in that goto texonomy order. Here I am attaching screenshot for your reference. https://prnt.sc/o8z5tg

Comment: Thank you again, but I already tried that plugin, but didn't work in admin.

Comment: I mean I could change order with that plugin, but after pressing update button, it changes order.

Comment: Okay you mean you want to change order by just drag and drop without clicking update button. Am right?

Comment: I just want "not to change CATEGORIE's order" in "WORDPRESS 5.0 ADMIN" after pressing update button.
I'm not taking about front side.
Thank you anyway.